# Cómo obtener un texto que se encuentra dentro de unos simbolos

Tags: javascript

Me gustaría obtener el texto que se encuentra dentro de los simbolos *¡*  *!* yo sé cómo encontrar el texto pero no cómo buscar únicamente dentro de los simbolos...

```html
<div class="text">¡Hola a todos! esto es un texto</div>
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Qué has intentando y qué problema o error tienes?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un Regex para eso, por ejemplo así

```js
function captureData(data) {
  const matchData = data.match(/¡(.*)!/);
  
  if (matchData) {
    return matchData[1];
  } else {
    return '';
  }
}

console.log(captureData("¡asdasdasdsdasdad!"));
console.log(captureData("asdasdasd¡casa!asdasdad"));
console.log(captureData("no deberia haber match"));
```

Lo que hace la expresión es capturar todos los caracteres que se encuentren dentro de los signos de exclamación; el . hace referencia a cualquier caracter y el asterisco busca una coincidencia de 0 o más caracteres.